# Delete a specific string from a list of strings in a file python

Tags: python

I have a list like that:

```
['Alice,Female,1994\n', 'Bob,Male,1995\n', 'Carol,Male,1993\n', 'Felix,Male,1990\n',     'Giacomo,Male,1990\n', 'Irena,Female,1992\n', 'Joe,Male,1995\n', 'Leo,Male,1995\n', 'Marco,Male,1991\n', 'Tania,Female,1992\n', 'Lillo,Male,1994']
```

Then I want to remove one string just inserted the name (for example "Lillo") then I want to delete it also from a file. I did something like that but it does not work. I insert the name, looks like it check if the name exist but then, when I ask for showing the file, 'Lillo,Male,1994' is still there. Can you help me? Here is my code:

```
name = input("Insert the name you want to delete: ")
book = "data.txt"
f = open(book,'r')
line = f.readlines()
f.close()
print(line)
for p in range(len(line)):
    lineString = line[p].split(',')
    if lineString[0] == name:
        line.pop(p)
print(line)
```

USING THIS CODE FROM @ANON IT WORKS. But how to remove it from the file?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Be specific when asking questions like this

Comment: __never__ modify a list while iterating over it

Comment: So I should have to create a new list and then fill it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just process lines you have read into memory and write them to the file (replacing it's content):

```
name = input("Insert the name you want to delete: ")
# let's strip excessive whitespace and change to lower case:
name = name.strip().lower()
book = "data.txt"

# use 'with' construct to ensure that file is closed after use:
with open(book, 'r') as f: 
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

filtered = []
for line in lines:
    try: # guard against incorrect record, e.g. 'Guido, 1956'
        name_, sex, year = line.split(',')
    except ValueError:
        print("cannot unpack this line:", line)
        continue
    if name == name_.strip().lower():
        continue # we don't want this line, so we skip it
    filtered.append(line) # line is ok, we keep it

# join list of lines into one string and write to the file:
with open(book, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(filtered))
```

Comment: can you explain what splitlines is? I try it in python and it does not recognized it

Comment: so maybe I have to import string? Because python says to me AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Comment: sorry, my mistake. it should be `f.read().splitlines()` of course (already edited)

Answer (score 2):

never modify a list while iterating over it

instead filter your list

```
def test(line):
     this_name = line.split(",",1)[0]
     return name == this_name

name = input("Insert the name you want to delete: ")
book = "data.txt"
lines = open(book,'r').readlines()
with open(book,"wb") as f:
    f.write("\n".join( [line for line in lines if test(line)] ))
```

there is your whole assignment I hope you share with the other kids in your class

Comment: python gives me an error if I insert this type of text

Comment: I use the @Anon code and it works but it removes only from the list and not from the file

Comment: OP is using Python 3 (or at least `print_function`).

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
>>> lines = ['Alice,Female,1994\n', 'Bob,Male,1995\n', 'Carol,Male,1993\n', 'Felix,Male,1990\n',     'Giacomo,Male,1990\n', 'Irena,Female,1992\n', 'Joe,Male,1995\n', 'Leo,Male,1995\n', 'Marco,Male,1991\n', 'Tania,Female,1992\n', 'Lillo,Male,1994']
>>> lines = [l.strip() for l in lines]
>>> to_remove = 'Giacomo'
>>> lines_with_removed = [l for l in lines if not l.startswith(to_remove)]
>>> lines_with_removed
['Alice,Female,1994', 'Bob,Male,1995', 'Carol,Male,1993', 'Felix,Male,1990', 'Irena,Female,1992', 'Joe,Male,1995', 'Leo,Male,1995', 'Marco,Male,1991', 'Tania,Female,1992', 'Lillo,Male,1994']
```

Firstly, when you read a line, the newline character gets read, so you could do this to remove the newline char:

```
lines = [l.strip() for l in lines]
```

Next, since the name always comes in the first column of the comma, you could just use:

```
lines_with_removed = [l for l in lines if not l.startswith(to_remove)]
```

Alternatively, you could try `csv` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: python gives me an error if I insert this type of text

Comment: Is there the possibility to move the code in python model like I wrote it?

Comment: because you must remove the `>>>` , type out line by line without the `>>>`

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to open the file for writing if you want to change what's in the file.  We can also use range(len()) to go by index value, rather than the line.  That'll help with the popping

```
for p in range(len(line)):
    lineString = line[p].split(',')
    if lineString[0] == name:
        line.pop(p)
```

So that'll fix that.

Now you want to re-open the file with 'w' permissions to over-write it with the new list using a for-loop.

Comment: no it wont ... it will get bad indexes ... it will work in some instances but the indexing will start skipping entries

Comment: it technically works because it delete the string but how to delete it also from the file?

Comment: this is not how you should be doing it .... it will break on one of the cases that your teacher will probably give you

Answer (score 0):

the simple one:

```
line=['Alice,Female,1994\n', 'Bob,Male,1995\n', 'Carol,Male,1993\n', 'Felix,Male,1990\n',     'Giacomo,Male,1990\n', 'Irena,Female,1992\n', 'Joe,Male,1995\n', 'Leo,Male,1995\n', 'Marco,Male,1991\n', 'Tania,Female,1992\n', 'Lillo,Male,1994']
to_remove = 'carol'
new_line = [ x for x in line if not x.strip().lower().find(to_remove.lower()) ]
new_line
```

['Alice,Female,1994\n', 'Bob,Male,1995\n', 'Felix,Male,1990\n', 'Giacomo,Male,19
90\n', 'Irena,Female,1992\n', 'Joe,Male,1995\n', 'Leo,Male,1995\n', 'Marco,Male,
1991\n', 'Tania,Female,1992\n', 'Lillo,Male,1994\n']

Comment: `if not to_remove in x.lower()` is much simpler... also `to_remove.lower` returns function, so you'll get an error

Comment: thats some tricky stuff you are doing with find to ensure it is found at the 0 index ...